# Flask form not validating when csrf token is included

Tags: python, flask, web

I have a flask form that I am using to get input to pass into a class. When I am trying to submit it, it is not showing any error and just reloading the same page. I have made sure that the csrf token is included in the jinja template as well. Here is the code:

**Forms.py**

```py
class addTripForm(FlaskForm):
    location = StringField('Location', validators=[DataRequired()])
    startdate = DateField('Start Date', format='%Y=%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()])
    enddate = DateField('End Date', format='%Y=%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**app.py**

```py
def check_form(form):
    print(form.errors)
    if form.submit():
        print("submitted")
    if form.validate():
        print("validated")

@app.route('/add', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add():
    form = addTripForm(request.form)
    check_form(form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # if form is valid, use fields to create and store a trip
        print("adding trip")
        user.add_trip(form.location.data,
                        form.startdate.data,
                        form.enddate.data)
        return redirect('/trips')
    return render_template('add.html', form=form)
```

**add.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<body>
<h3> Select a location and date range</h3>
<form action="" method="POST" name="addtrip">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.location.label }} {{form.location}}
    {{ form.startdate.label }} {{ form.startdate(class='datepicker') }}
    {{ form.enddate.label }} {{form.enddate(class='datapicker')}}

    <p>
    {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-primary') }}
    </p>
</form>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your DateFields' format to '%Y-%m-%d' from '%Y=%m-%d' and then your code will work. The date value is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd in the HTTP Request.